# Logging working fine in Mozilla and chrome but gives error in internet Explorer

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Logging working fine in Mozilla and chrome but gives error in internet Explorer for security hash function in Cakephp.

Comment: Please add a code sample and error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

In IE (depending on the version) you might need to open the console to prevent an error. If the console is not visible, it may cause a error. Did you have the console open? (hotkey: F12)